# How to delete a value in a list without using .remove?

Tags: python, list

I have

```
x = 1

list = [1,2,3]
```

I want to remove the 1 in the list by referencing its *value* of x,not the index - without using list.remove(x). How is this possible?

Comment: What's wrong with remove?

Comment: Nothing, I'm just wondering if there is another way in python to accomplish this.

Comment: Its Python you are using. Don't have to re-invent wheels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, there is a lot of way to do that.

```
x = 5
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9, 4]

del my_list[my_list.index(x)]
```

or

```
my_list.pop(my_list.index(x))
```

Comment: But what if I don't know the index of x, just the value?

Comment: But this code do exactly that! You can change x to any value you want.

Comment: Ohh! Sorry I'm sorda new to Python, it took me a second to fully understand your code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
x = 1
list = [1,2,3]
list = [i for i in list if i != x]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [1,2,3]
list = [i for i in list if i is not 1]
```

Comment: OP says "I want to remove the 1 in the list by referencing its value of x", so it seems the code ought to use `x`